# Boost Python def member function that calls static function with self as only argument

Tags: python, c++, boost

So I've gotten to the point where I need to start wrapping a lot of functionality of [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.7/index.html) into my embedded Python module.

One of the nice things about GLM is that it defines all it's typical vector math functions (`length`, `normalize` etc.) as free-standing static functions. This works lovely when writing C++, but it's throwing a wrench in things when trying to wrap this functionality as part of a class definition.

I want to call `len` on my `Vec3F` class and have it call the correct overload of `length` while passing `self` as the first and only argument. The Boost.Python documentation is fairly opaque and there's not a lot of examples, so I don't even know if this is possible.

Implementing a `length` function in the `vec2` and `vec3` structs is not possible, since these structs are in another project; I have to deal with the structs as-is.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

## Python Interface

```
Vec3F v
v.x = 1.0
v.y = 1.0
v.z = 1.0
print len(v) # should print 1.732050...
```

## Module Definition

```
template<typename T>
struct vec2
{
    T x;
    T y;
};

template<typename T>
struct vec3
{
    T x;
    T y;
    T z;
};

template<typename T>
float length(vec2& v)
{
    return sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y);
}

template<typename T>
float length(vec3& v)
{
    return sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y + v.z * v.z);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(naga)
{
    class_<vec2<float>, "Vec2F")
        .def("x", &vec2<float>::x)
        .def("y", &vec2<float>::y)
        .def("__len__", /* ??? */); // not sure what needs to be here!

    class_<vec3<float>, "Vec3F")
        .def("x", &vec2<float>::x)
        .def("y", &vec2<float>::y)
        .def("__len__", /* ??? */);  // not sure what needs to be here!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a wrapper class but still `__len__` is not going to return the correct result probably because the return value is converted into integer internally (I suspect `__len__` must always return integer value). 
So you will need to expose it as `len` to get correct floating point return value.

```
namespace bp = boost::python;

template<typename T>
struct vec2
{
    T x;
    T y;
};

template<typename T>
struct vec3
{
    T x;
    T y;
    T z;
};

template <typename T>
struct vec2_wrapper : vec2<T>
{
    float length()
    {
        return sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct vec3_wrapper : vec3<T>
{
    float length()
    {
        return sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(naga)
{
    bp::class_ < vec2_wrapper<float> >("Vec2F")
        .def_readwrite("x", &vec2_wrapper<float>::x)
        .def_readwrite("y", &vec2_wrapper<float>::y)
        .def("__len__", &vec2_wrapper<float>::length)
        .def("len", &vec2_wrapper<float>::length)
        ;

    bp::class_ < vec3_wrapper<float> >("Vec3F")
        .def_readwrite("x", &vec3_wrapper<float>::x)
        .def_readwrite("y", &vec3_wrapper<float>::y)
        .def_readwrite("z", &vec3_wrapper<float>::z)
        .def("__len__", &vec3_wrapper<float>::length)
        .def("len", &vec3_wrapper<float>::length)
        ;
}
```

Python test:

```
import naga as vec

v = vec.Vec3F()
v.x = 1.0
v.y = 1.0
v.z = 1.0
print "len(v):", len(v)
print "v.len():", v.len()
```

Output:

```
len(v): 1
v.len(): 1.73205077648
```